# How to reduce combination of nested for and if loops in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two big dataframes and my aim to calculate geographical distance between each and every lat/long in first dataframe to all the lat/longs in second dataframe. for this I am using haversine function. I want reduce the time taken to run this loop.Is there any alternate ways to write this code more efficiently.

```
for i in range(0,len(df1)):
    BS = (df1['Latitude'][i],df1['Longitude'][i])
    for j in range(0,len(df0)):
        if (abs(df1['Latitude'][i]-df0['Cust_lat'][j])<=0.1 and abs(df1['Longitude'][i]-
              df0['Cust_long'][j])<=0.1):
            CPE = (df0['Cust_lat'][j],df0['Cust_long'][j])      
            if(haversine(BS,CPE)<= radius):
                distance=haversine(BS,CPE)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example: some data and all the functions you're using (e.g. haversine).

Comment: Multiprocessing will help. or write this function in c++ and make a wrapper of it in python using swig. This will speed up your process.